# Proper way to extract JSON data from the web given an API

Tags: python, json

I have an URL in the form of

```
http://site.com/source.json?s=
```

And I wish to use Python to create a class that will allow me to parse in my "s" query, send it to that site, and extract out the JSON results.

I've tried importing json/setting up the class, but nothing ever really works and I'm trying to learn good practices at the same time. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should (especially when starting out), use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. This would enable your code to be:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://site.com/source.json', params={'s': 'somevalue/or other here'})
json_result = r.json()
```

This automatically escapes the parameters, and automatically converts your JSON result into a Python dict....

Comment: Any reason to import requests over json? And how might I fit this into a general class structure?

Comment: @JohnSmith what is a "general class structure". `requests` uses `json` under the hood - if it gets a json response, it's automatically retrievable from calling `.json()

Comment: "No module named requests" -- is this some third party lib?

Comment: @JohnSmith yes - did the follow the link?

Comment: Well I am trying to learn how to turn this into something object-oriented, so I guess I am asking "where would this request.get code normally go? Where would the dict be stored, etc?"

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm not sure that aspect of your question is specific enough. All depends on your design and requirements. Which are probably going to be too broad to be reasonably answerable.